# getting "Enumeration yielded no results" error in LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I have a repeater inside a repeater. And I am binding inner repeater on parent repeater's `ItemDataBound` event with `myEventDetails list()`. And I am getting this `myEventDetails list()` inside `page_load`.

So When I use the following linq query I am getting

> "Enumeration yielded no results"

and inner repeater has empty values.

```
protected void parentRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

        Repeater inner = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("innerRepeater"));


        var allEvents = from x in myEventDetails
                   where x.event_name == "test"
                   select new
                   {
                       EventName = x.event_name,
                       EventID = x.event_id
                   };

        inner.DataSource = allEvents;
        inner.DataBind();
    }
}
```

When I am debugging I am getting values in to the `myEventDetails list()`. So it is not empty.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the type of `myEventDetails`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it because you are not matching the right text? Try using ToLower

```
 where x.event_name.ToLower() == "test"
```

Answer (score 2):

It says that there is no element with `event_name == "test"` in your `myEventDetails` collection.

Comment: But I do have values with event name as "test" in the collection.

Comment: yes I am seeing this error in debugger! at the same time I am able to see the "test" event name in the myEventDetails collection also.

Comment: It just shows that there is no items to enumerate over. Verify carefully what data you have in `myEventDetails` collection at the time of binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `ToList()`:

```
inner.DataSource = allEvents.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is myEventDetails coming from? Is it a field/property on the class?

Can you assign allEvents.ToList() to another variable, and see if that helps? I've had weird issues like this before that seemed to be solved by doing that...I never did quite figure out why, but it's worth a try.